# How to debug a C++ static library using Eclipse CDT in Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, static-libraries

I am using Eclicpse to develop a static library made of functions that I use often.
I have done so creating a "C++ -> Static Library" project in my workspace.

In the same workspace I have created an other project "Test" that I use to test that my functions work as expected. I have linked the libraries to this project and I am able to use the library in my code.

One of my functions has some problems and I would like to debug it. If I run "Debug" in Eclipse on my test project I can't however "step in" the function that is causing problems.

How can I achieve this? Alternatively which is a good way by which I can test and debug my static libraries in Eclipse?

Comment: Do the test application link with the debug build of the library?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg if it's not done automatically by eclipse probably not. I usually link to the release version..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile the static libraries with debug information.

Go to [Properties] -> [C/C++ Build] -> [Settings] -> [GCC C++ Application] -> [Debugging] and turn on debugging and make sure the build is set to debug configuration.